# Getting delimiters in Java pattern matching

Tags: java, split, design-patterns, delimiter

Given a pattern, we can slice a string `S` into multiple parts with `S.split(pattern)`.  However, the result is not what I want.  I want those strings that match the pattern, i.e. delimiters.  My idea is to use the split result to form a new pattern then split again, but that needs to consider tons of cases for various meta symbols.  Any straightforward way?

Comment: An example will help us to help you

Comment: Doesn't regex have a kind of 'not' operator?  E.G. in pseudo-code `S.split(!pattern)`

Comment: Thanks for all the replies.  I figoured this out.  It's simple but convoluted.  The pattern gives a matcher, which has methods of find and group that will get me the first pattern matched, then loop through to get all patterns matched.  I wish that String had a method that would return all patterns as opposed to split.

Answer (score 3):

Look at Java regex:

http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/regex/Pattern.html

Comment: It is best to link to the latest version of the JavaDocs. I have edited your answer to point to J2SE 7. For tips on getting a link to the latest docs, see [point 2 of advantages](http://bugs.sun.com/bugdatabase/view_bug.do?bug_id=7090875).

Comment: As @AndrewThompson pointed out in the comment under your question, regex has a `not` operator that you can use.

Comment: The not operator won't work, because it would return incorrect results on a string with back-to-back delimiters. (IE two spaces in a row on a space delimited string.)

Answer (score 2):

You can't just run multiple splits or you can potentially get an incorrect result.  I'd probably use s.split(pattern,2)...

```
public static Vector<String> getDelims( String s, String pattern )
{
    String[] items = s.split( pattern, 2 );
    if( items.length == 1 ) return new Vector<String>();
    String delim = s.substring( items[0].length());
    delim = delim.substring(0, delim.length() - items[1].length() );      
    Vector<String> ret = getDelims(items[1], pattern);
    ret.add(0, delim);
    return ret;
}
```